# draw(_ rect: CGRect) distortion on different iOS versions

Tags: ios, swift, operating-system

I'm doing a searchBar for studies, but I found some distortion in the layout in different versions of iOS, I don't remember and I don't know any relevant changes between the OS that can accomplish this, I'm a little lost.

```
override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    drawPosition()
}
```

> iOS 15
> [image]

> iOS 12.4
> [image]

```
private lazy var widthLeftView: CGFloat = 0.0

private func drawPosition() {
    searchView.addSubview(searchIcon)
    
    widthConstraint = searchView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: calculateWidthLeftView())

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        searchView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchViewSize),
        widthConstraint,
        searchIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchIconSize),
        searchIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchIconSize),
        searchIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.centerYAnchor),
        searchIcon.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: searchView.trailingAnchor,
            constant: 0)
    ])
    searchBarTextField.leftView = searchView
    searchBarTextField.leftViewMode = .always
}

private func calculateWidthLeftView() -> Double {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    let widht = self.frame.size.width - 54
    let widhLeft = widht / 2
    return widhLeft
}
```

Comment: Please post necessary code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @udi  I added the parts that I thought were relevant, is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by removing the override draw() function and putting it to be called inside the override layoutSubViews

```
public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    drawPosition()
}
```

This decision was good for two reasons, first it fixed the bug, and second, I found that overwriting draw() impacts performance and fills up the iPhone's memory little by little,